# Barcode scanner auto-return feature

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I'm attempting to build a very simple app that displays a webview to a site which contains a field to input product upc information. Only reason for the app is to provide our warehouse employees with a built in barcode scanner feature. All works well so far, up to inserting the scanned barcode information into the textfield with the following code:

webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.activeElement.value='\(text)'")

The problem I've run into is I am trying to code a way for the form to submit/search immediately following scan. As of now, the Search button does not even appear as using the value property does not seem to register as text input.

I have searched (perhaps incorrectly) for hours online for a similar issue and the only resolve I can think of is simulating keypresses with the textfield focused. At best, a simple keypress for the Enter key. However, with the search button not appearing until text is actually typed on the onscreen keyboard, I'm wondering if a combination of Space/Delete keys are needed, followed by the Enter key. So far, nothing has worked and I'd love some suggestions on what approach should be used here.

Comment: Can you try manually firing the change event after inputting the value, `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true })))`

Comment: @thatguytyler thank you, that helped! Adding that command did enable the Search button. User can then hit Return on the onscreen keyboard to submit. However, I'm looking for a way to then simulate the Return key, or to auto-submit the search function.

Comment: Now that submit is available, can you select and simulate the click event? `document.getElementById('ID').click()`.  I'm not sure what the HTML of the submit button looks like, if you post it I can help more.

Comment: I'm going to add an answer to lay out everything more clearly

Comment: This is a hosted webpage that I do not have access to. I could get the ID for this particular textfield but I'm looking for a more generic resolution for a simple scan and submit feature that would work on other forms. Detecting changes with the dispatchEvent function got half of that completed though. Is there a way to then trigger a keypress event through Javascript or Swift?

Comment: see my answer, since that element is focused you can simulate a enter keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If submit is not visible it's probably due to a change event not firing, simulate the change event after filling a text value.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }))")
```

after the change event we can target the button and fire the click event.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("var btn = document.querySelector('button')if(btn.textContent.includes('Search')){btn.click()}")
```

Comment: Thought that was it! Unfortunately, although there's no errors, it is not submitting as expected. Same as before, first part works great but there's no changes with the KeyboardEvent. However, if the return key is hit on the onscreen keyboard, search function fires.

Comment: Hmm, lets try an expanded keydown event, I've updated my 2nd snippet above.  Does the form submit with the 'enter' key and the 'return' key.  The one on the main keyboard as well as the numbpad?

Comment: Same result. Yes, on desktop the form will submit with both Enter keys.

Comment: Is this a HTML form or something else? Are you able to post a sample of the HTML you're interacting with?

Comment: <input name="searchproduct" type="search" md-maxlength="30" vip-clear-input="" vipautofocus="" vipclearfunction="scanitemCtrl.clearSearch('searchproduct')" allupper="" select-on-click="" ng-change="scanitemCtrl.modelChange()" ng-model="scanitemCtrl.searchproduct" ng-model-options="Page.getDebounce()" vip-on-enter="scanitemCtrl.findproduct()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid vipclearable md-input ng-empty ng-valid-md-maxlength ng-not-modified ng-touched" id="input_23" style="text-transform: uppercase;" aria-invalid="false">      This is the textfield that is focused when searching. Hope that helps!

Comment: <button class="md-primary md-button md-indigo-theme md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" tabindex="-1" ng-if="scanitemCtrl.searchproduct != null" ng-click="scanitemCtrl.findproduct()" style="">
                                <md-icon class="md-indigo-theme material-icons" role="img" aria-label="search">search</md-icon>
                                Search
                            </button>        This is the search button that appears after the change Event

Comment: Ok this is an angular page, you might try the 'keyup' instead of 'keydown'. Since this is angular the event bindings might be a bit different, let me research it a bit.

Comment: You may also need to add a brief timeout (150) better you do the next command after the change event.

Comment: I'm trying that with a few variations of your suggestion. The code executes with result 70 but still not submitting search function. I'm sure I have the syntax wrong, but with no error it seems to be correct. Thank you so much for your input, I will mark your suggestion as the answer as it 's the closest I've gotten with this. This is the syntax I'm trying, is the timeout written incorrectly?      webView.evaluateJavaScript("setTimeout(function() { document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {code: 'Enter',key: 'Enter',charCode: 13,keyCode: 13,bubbles: true})); }, 150)")

Comment: Your code looks ok there, but here's a snippet:
`webView.evaluateJavaScript("setTimeout(function() {document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {code: 'Enter',key: 'Enter',charCode: 13,keyCode: 13,bubbles: true}));document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {code: 'Enter',key: 'Enter',charCode: 13,keyCode: 13,bubbles: true}));}, 150)")`

Comment: @MikeF lets try a click event again maybe too:
`webView.evaluateJavaScript("var btn = document.querySelector('button')if(btn.textContent.includes('Search')){btn.click()}")`

Comment: Neither worked. Using the button click code produces nil result, using the timeout code produced result code 66(can't find what that means?).

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the input and submit a form accordingly

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
  // code to search barcode
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name"/>
<p id="values"></p>
```